# PHP: From static text to displaying the value in the variable

Tags: php, variables, conditional-statements

I have been trying to figure out what exactly is it that my instructor means when he says "instead of a static piece of information, change that information to display the value inside your variable". If my variable is company and samsung is my conditional, what exactly does he want me to do? This is the code that he is referencing to: Thanks in advance for any input.

```
$company = samsung;
```

Comment: You mean $company = "samsung";?

Comment: or was he trying to say `Dynamic Variables` i.e. `Variable Variables`?

Comment: Well, assuming that your teacher knows what he is doing, it seems you have misunderstood his assignment/directions. In that case you need to ask him to clarify it. It could also be that you are not explaining the problem very well to us.